# How to pass variables from setup to tests in nosetest?

Tags: python, nose

With python and nosetests I have the following setup:

```
- package
    - __init__.py
    - test1.py
    - test2.py
```

The `__init__.py` module contains a set up function

```
def setup():
    print("Setup called")
    var = 42
```

which will be used later to create a unique identified (different between running the tests, but the same for all the tests inside the package).

How can the tests itself access this variable (in this example case `var`)? The test scripts are just some stubs:

```
from nose.tools import assert_true

class TestSuite(object):
    def test1(self):
        # How to get content of 'var' here?
        assert_true(True)
```

Is there some pythonic way to do this, or just use an environment variable to do this?

Answer (score 1):

nose calls `.setup()` methods inside classes:

```
class Test:
    def setup(self):
        self.var = 1

    def test_print_var(self):
        print(self.var)
```

This also applies to methods inherited from elsewhere:

```
class TestBase:
    def setup(self):
        self.var = 1

class Test(TestBase):
    def test_print_var(self):
        print(self.var)
```